# how to get the last part of a string before a certain character?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split, slice

I am trying to print the last part of a string before a certain character.

I'm not quite sure whether to use the string .split() method or string slicing or maybe something else.

Here is some code that doesn't work but I think shows the logic:

```
x = 'http://test.com/lalala-134'
print x['-':0] # beginning at the end of the string, return everything before '-'
```

Note that the number at the end will vary in size so I can't set an exact count from the end of the string.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You are looking for [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit), with a limit:

```
print x.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
```

`.rsplit()` searches for the splitting string from the end of input string, and the second argument limits how many times it'll split to just once.

Another option is to use [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition), which will only ever split just once:

```
print x.rpartition('-')[0]
```

For splitting just once, `str.rpartition()` is the faster method as well; if you need to split more than once you can only use `str.rsplit()`.

Demo:

```
>>> x = 'http://test.com/lalala-134'
>>> print x.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
http://test.com/lalala
>>> 'something-with-a-lot-of-dashes'.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
'something-with-a-lot-of'
```

and the same with `str.rpartition()`

```
>>> print x.rpartition('-')[0]
http://test.com/lalala
>>> 'something-with-a-lot-of-dashes'.rpartition('-')[0]
'something-with-a-lot-of'
```

Comment: thank you very much, i used `print x.rsplit('-',1)[1]` and it worked, thank you. i had also just come across `print x.rpartition('-')[2]` and that seemed to work too! thanks again!

Comment: Right, your wording was a little ambiguous; you asked for * last part of a string **before** a certain character*; you meant after, I guess. :-)

Comment: but my wonderful comments! 'beginning at the end of the string', i see what you mean haha.

Answer (score 5):

Difference between ***split*** and ***partition*** is split returns the list **without** delimiter and will split where ever it gets delimiter in string i.e.

```
x = 'http://test.com/lalala-134-431'

a,b,c = x.split(-)
print(a)
"http://test.com/lalala"
print(b)
"134"
print(c)
"431"
```

and ***partition*** will divide the string with only **first** delimiter and will only return 3 values in list

```
x = 'http://test.com/lalala-134-431'
a,b,c = x.partition('-')
print(a)
"http://test.com/lalala"
print(b)
"-"
print(c)
"134-431"
```

so as you want last value you can use ***rpartition*** it works in same way but it will find delimiter from end of string

```
x = 'http://test.com/lalala-134-431'
a,b,c = x.rpartition('-')
print(a)
"http://test.com/lalala-134"
print(b)
"-"
print(c)
"431"
```

Comment: Last example should be x.rpartition instead of x.partition, yes?