# Regex capture all before substring

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
s = 'Abc - 33 SR 11 Kill(s) P G - (Type-1P-G) 2 Kill(s) M 1 Kill(s) S - M9A CWS 1 Kill(s) 11 Kill(s)'
```

I'm trying to split this up to capture the number of kills, and the information before each `"XY Kill(s)"` to get this output:

```
['Abc - 33 SR', 
 'P G - (Type-1P-G)', 
 'M', 
 'S - M9A CWS']
```

Getting the number of kills was simple:

```
re.findall(r"(\d+) Kill", s)
['11', '2', '1', '1', '11']
```

Getting the text has been harder. From researching, I have tried to use the following regex, which just gave the beginning of a series of capture groups:

```
re.findall(r"(?=[0-9]+ Kill)", s)
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I then changed this to add in "any number of characters before each group".

```
re.findall(r"(.+)(?=[0-9]+ Kill)", s)
['Abc - 33 SR 11 Kill(s) P G - (Type-1P-G) 2 Kill(s) M 1 Kill(s) S - M9A CWS 1 Kill(s) 1']
```

This just gives the entire string. How can I adjust this to capture everything before "any number of digits-space-Kill"?

Let's get the dupes out of the way. I've consulted the following. The second in particular looked useful but I've been unable to make it suit this purpose.

[Extract Number before a Character in a String Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167442/extract-number-before-a-character-in-a-string-using-python),

[How would I get everything before a : in a string Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387415/how-would-i-get-everything-before-a-in-a-string-python),

[how to get the last part of a string before a certain character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851568/how-to-get-the-last-part-of-a-string-before-a-certain-character).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963691/python-regex-multiple-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(.*?)\s*(\d+) Kill\(s\)\s*', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XK0BYH/1)

**Details**

- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 2: one or more digits
- `Kill(s)` - a space and `Kill(s)` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/bCKhBa):

```
import re
rx = r"(.*?)\s*(\d+) Kill\(s\)\s*"
s = "Abc - 33 SR 11 Kill(s) P G - (Type-1P-G) 2 Kill(s) M 1 Kill(s) S - M9A CWS 1 Kill(s) 11 Kill(s)"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
```

Output:

```
[('Abc - 33 SR', '11'), ('P G - (Type-1P-G)', '2'), ('M', '1'), ('S - M9A CWS', '1'), ('', '11')]
```

Comment: You can also replace the space by \s+ in the RegEx

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Well, that is part of the original pattern and it is a literal, so it is OK as is, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to get a list of all content *between* matches.

```
>>> re.split(r"\d+ Kill\(s\)", s)
    ['Abc - 33 SR ', ' P G - (Type-1P-G) ', ' M ', ' S - M9A CWS ', ' ', '']
```

You can clean it up to remove whitespace and empty strings.

```
>>> [s.strip() for s in re.split(r"\d+ Kill\(s\)", s) if s.strip()]
    ['Abc - 33 SR', 'P G - (Type-1P-G)', 'M', 'S - M9A CWS']
```